# Build IOS in react native error & i have tried many solving in stackoverflow and get the same result

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have install pod with
`sudogem install cocoapod`
and i go to cd ios
`pod install`
I back to the root folder with cd.. and then i got an error like this in npx react-native run-ios

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace Coba.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme Coba -destination id=FF773279-AF11-427F-B143-6710FDC96901

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace

Create build description
Build description signature: 487e43c39af0dba249eeade4b390f99c
Build description path: /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coba-acjtaskcgfbphugcderpdiliwjum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/487e43c39af0dba249eeade4b390f99c-desc.xcbuild

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
CompileC /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coba-acjtaskcgfbphugcderpdiliwjum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/json.o /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/json.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII

CompileC /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coba-acjtaskcgfbphugcderpdiliwjum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/String.o /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/String.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    

CompileC /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coba-acjtaskcgfbphugcderpdiliwjum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    Native/Coba/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/net/NetOps.h:25:

/Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile - React Native/Coba/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/Time.h:47:9: warning: 'CLOCK_REALTIME' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define CLOCK_REALTIME 0


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/mymac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coba-acjtaskcgfbphugcderpdiliwjum/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/mymac/Nicholas/Mobile\ -\ React\ Native/Coba/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

if someone can help me for solving this problem, i got so confuse for resolve this problem. I have try many thins in stackoverflow but still like this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing cocoapods with brew solved a lot of my problems. It might help you as well